# Comparing LocalTime returns true, even tho debugger evaluates to false

Tags: java, validation, debugging, localtime

So, I am currently working on a function that checks if a given `LocalTime` is inside a range. All good, and the equivalent for `LocalDateTime` works without an issue.

So, my code right now looks like this:

```java
    public boolean isInRange(LocalTime time){
        return (time.isAfter(roundedStartTime.toLocalTime())) || time.equals(roundedStartTime.toLocalTime()) &&
            time.isBefore(roundedEndTime.toLocalTime());
    }
```

It has some specifics for my business logic, but thats not part of the issue. I also have accompanying junit tests, that check if the logic works as intended. Again, the `inRange(LocalDateTime time)` function works flawlessly.

But using my tests, *with the same time I use for the* `LocalDateTime`*verification*, they fail, as they somehow return true. I've started debugging, and can't quite believe my eyes, which explains the `true && false`check:

[image]

For whatever reason, evaluating the two statements separately shows the expected behaviour, but combining them, returns true.

Comment: You need to set appropriate parenthesis if you want your condition to be evaluated as `(A || B) && C`. Currently it gets evaluated as `A  || (B && C)` because && has a higher precedence than ||. Meaning as soon as the first condition is true everything is true and not even evaluated because of short-circuiting.

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that, I close the bracket too soon. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function of

```
    public boolean isInRange(LocalTime time){
        return (time.isAfter(roundedStartTime.toLocalTime())) || time.equals(roundedStartTime.toLocalTime()) &&
            time.isBefore(roundedEndTime.toLocalTime());
    }
```

Is checking whether

> `time` is after `roundedStartTime`
>
> or
>
> `time` `equals` `roundedStartTime`
>
> and
>
> `time` is before `roundedEndTime`

Looking at the [Java operator precedence table](https://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/%7Eguvenir/courses/CS101/op_precedence.html) we can conclude that `&&` has a precedence of **4**, while `||` has a precedence of **3**. As a result, your condition is checking whether (time equals roundedStartTime and before roundedEndTime) or (time is after roundedStartTime).

So, when your `time` is after `roundedStartTime` and after `roundedEndTime`, that is, it's later than the whole range, the condition will still be evaluated to true, because the first operand of `||` evaluated to true. To fix it, you will need to wrap paranthesis around your `||`, so your logical expression will evaluate to

(time >= roundedStartTime) and (time < roundedEndTime)

Fix:

```
    public boolean isInRange(LocalTime time){
        return ((time.isAfter(roundedStartTime.toLocalTime())) || time.equals(roundedStartTime.toLocalTime())) &&
            time.isBefore(roundedEndTime.toLocalTime());
    }
```